# Typescript variable name change on import

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have got a problem.
My TypeScript code is

```js
import settings from './settings';
import YouTube from 'simple-youtube-api';

const youtube = new YouTube(settings.googleToken);
```

When I am compiling it with tsconfig.json:

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "lib": ["esnext"],
        "outDir": "build",
        "rootDir": "src",
        "noImplicitUseStrict": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ]
    }
}
```

it ends up with this code:

```js
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const settings = require('./settings');
const simple_youtube_api_1 = require("simple-youtube-api");

const youtube = new simple_youtube_api_1.default(settings.googleToken);
```

How can I prevent the variable names changes and what should I change in tsconfig.json to remove the top line (Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });)?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: out of curiosity, why would you need it?

Comment: This is how transpilation works by default-what specific problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am trying to have the same variable names as in .ts file.

Comment: And why do you need this? Is your transpiled code broken because of some inconsistent rename?